# What happened to OD?

Tags: gatchaman-crowds

After OD fights Berg Katze he meetings up with Rui and hands him his note back covering up the blood coming down his arm. we also see a shot of his back all cut up. after Rui leaves OD's arm begins to bleed profusely before he collapsed.

Now at the end we don't see OD no one makes mention that he died and Joe bled just as much after being beaten by Berg Katze. ao i am wondering, what happened to OD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you watch the [OVA episode](http://myanimelist.net/anime/23703/Gatchaman_Crowds:_Embrace/) (director's cut of episode 12, released with the BD/DVD box release), you will know that

> OD is alive, since he was healed by Utsutsu.

Comment: please read though [this page](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) about answering questions here. there are also other guidelines such as the posting of illegal sites as we don't support piracy (in which illegal streaming sites are). also i believe the second part is meant to answer another question.

Comment: Though I've edited your answer, please take a look at [this](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) for future reference.

Comment: I got Hanabee's [DVD Release](http://hanabee.myshopify.com/collections/everything/products/gatchaman-crowds) and i didn't see this directors cut episode and there's no listed extras for the [BluRay](http://hanabee.myshopify.com/collections/everything/products/gatchaman-crowds-bluray) so the BD/DVD box release must be either not an Australian Release or it was never released outside japan